Aubio (aubioonset.exe) on Windows - can't find ffmpeg libraries
I have installed Aubio on Windows but when trying to use the tools, like aubioonset.exe, I am faced with the following error message:
C:/Peter/aubio/aubio/aubio-0.4.6-win64-ffmpeg/bin/aubioonset.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I assume it looks after ffmpeg libraries. I have FFmpeg installed and bin-dir added to PATH environment variable. FFMPEG is working flawless globally.
After searching internet for answers to my issue I find "answers" like:
"install chosen libraries (for instance ffmpeg, with header files)"
That vague answer doesn't help me at all. Exactly how do I install ffmpeg libraries, with header files, so that the Aubio-tools can find them? I need specifics about what environmental-variables must be set - or - should the ffmpeg lib-files be placed in the Aubio Build folder somewhere, or what should I do?
And after doing that I am supposed to recompile and reinstall Aubio. I can do that.
This is btw. the result from ./waf configure when building my own Aubio-binaries (instead of downloading pre-builds):
peter@DESKTOP-I0KNADQ MINGW64 /c/Peter/aubio/aubio (master)
$ ./waf configure
Setting top to                           : C:\Peter\aubio\aubio
Setting out to                           : C:\Peter\aubio\aubio\build
Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler)         : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe
Checking for header stdlib.h             : yes
Checking for header stdio.h              : yes
Checking for header math.h               : yes
Checking for header string.h             : yes
Checking for header errno.h              : yes
Checking for header limits.h             : yes
Checking for header stdarg.h             : yes
Checking for header getopt.h             : not found
Checking for header unistd.h             : not found
Checking for library m                   : not found
Checking for C99 __VA_ARGS__ macro       : yes
Checking for size of smpl_t              : float
Checking for size of lsmp_t              : double
Checking if complex.h is enabled         : no
Checking for FFT implementation          : ooura
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for all libav libraries         : not found (missing avcodec)
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : not found
Checking if using source_wavread         : yes
Checking if using sink_wavwrite          : yes
Checking for program 'txt2man'           : not found
Checking for program 'doxygen'           : not found
Checking for program 'sphinx-build'      : not found
'configure' finished successfully (7.590s)

As can be seen above I have no problem building Aubio without external libraries.
So my guess is that I can go down two different paths for a solution here: either try building with all external libraries somehow prepared (I have tried but can't change the output of ./waf configure no matter what I do. I have cloned the ffmpeg source from github. I can't figure out where ./waf configure is looking for it). Or I can get the precompiled binaries to work, by somehow installing the external libraries.
I have tried both solutions in multiple ways, but fail getting any one of them to work.

Hum, I don't know aubio, but as for waf, the configure step is not building anything. To build you have to use ./waf build after the configuration step.
